# how to recover deleted VM after the end of credits?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I had some VMs in gogole cloud that were deleted when my credits ran out. I know that there is a 30 day period for storage, but for personal reasons I could not do it.

These VMs had my master's project, I am a student, and I really want to retrieve the content of these Vms. Thanks in advance.

Comment: While I am very sorry to hear about you potentially losing your data, unfortunately this is not the correct forum in which to ask this question. This site is dedicated to programming and programming related questions. You may be able to find help over at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) or maybe [Super User](https://superuser.com/) - although please take a look at the FAQ and Help section to be sure your question would fit and be on topic for those sites. I am making the assumption that you already reached out to google support.

Comment: If it has been longer than about 30 days, everything is gone. As a last resort, I would open a support ticket with Google directly from the Google console.

Answer (score 1):

As specified in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#recovering_data), you must manually export any data that you want to keep from your Compute Engine VMs before the trial period ends, as your data and resources are only available for 30 days after the free trial ends.